# How to Call Procedure With Dynamic SQL from View

Tags: mysql, view, procedure

I am trying to create a view that calls a procedure at initiation to compute 2 variables to be used in the WHERE clause. The query runs but will not save as a view as it appears procedure calls are not allowed.  I researched this and found some suggestions about using a Function, but in trying that, I get errors that dynamic SQL is not allowed in a function.
Is there a way to do what I am attempting?

Code snippet:

```
    CALL p_GetOutlierLimits('ROI_Imputed_Percent','DB1',@ClassicLowerROIPct, @ClassicUpperROIPct);
    CALL p_GetOutlierLimits('576_VMC_Sol_Savings_Pct','DB2',@vmctcoLower149Pct, @vmctcoUpper149Pct);
    
    USE Database;
    SELECT 
       {CODE}
    from TABLE
    WHERE ROI_Imputed_Percent BETWEEN @ClassicLowerROIPct AND @ClassicUpperROIPct;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another way to do this by removing the calls from the view and just performing them from another procedure that accesses the view.